# Installing laravel in windows with XAMPP

Tags: laravel, xampp

I recently install Laravel in my laptop. I have no problem when i install it. The problem now is when i'm trying to use `punya.by` instead of `localhost:84/laravel/public`.

I install my XAMPP in `Disk : D`

```
<VirtualHost punya.by:84>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/public"
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ServerAdmin punya.by
    <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/laravel">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and here is my Hosts

```
127.0.0.1  punya.by
```

there is no problem when i access it with `localhost:84/laravel/public` but when i access it with punya.by . I get this

```
Not Found

HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.
```

So how to fix this ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access it by `punya.by:84`
Since it's listening on port 84, doesn't matter if you try to access it via IP or domain.

**EDIT:**
You need to define the vhost like this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:84>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/public"
    ServerName punya.by
    <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Deny from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Basically, the virtual host listens to an IP:Port combination and only inside the declaration do you define the domain that will be matched.

Comment: when i access that. It's open xampp dashboard

Comment: Looks like the virtual hosts are not in effect, are they in a separate file? Do you load the file in httpd.conf?

Comment: Here is the part of my httpd.conf.`
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Comment: its working when i access it with this `http://punya.by:84/laravel/public/`

Comment: Any chance the directory structure is in fact `laravel/public/laravel/public`?

Comment: You helping me. Thanks